# Unzipping files in netduino

Tags: unzip, epub, .net-micro-framework

I'm working on a school project that involves unzipping files in a netduino.
Basicly I have to do an eBook reader. For the scope of the project I'll be using [.ePub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) format wich is a free and standar e-Book format.
The e-Books will be loaded to de micro sd card. My major roadblock right now is that the ePub format consists in a zipfile with xhtml, css, and other metadata. This means that I have to unzip these files in the netduino.
Are there any lightweight unzip classes that might work in NETMF?